# Is it possible to implement a feature like Java's CompletableFuture::complete in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rayon

I'm a beginner in rust, and I'm trying to use rust's asynchronous programming.

In my requirement scenario, I want to create a empty Future and complete it in another thread after a complex multi-round scheduling process. The CompletableFuture::complete of Java can meet my needs very well.

I have tried to find an implementation of Rust, but haven't found one yet.

Is it possible to do it in Rust?

I understand from the comments below that using a channel for this is more in line with rust's design.

My scenario is a hierarchical scheduling executor.
For example, Task1 will be splitted to several Drivers, each Driver will use multi thread(rayon threadpool) to do some computation work, and the former driver's state change will trigger the execution of next driver, the result of the whole task is the last driver's output and the intermedia drivers have no output. That is to say, my async function cannot get result from one spawn task directly, so I need a shared stack variable or a channel to transfer the result.

So what I really want is this: the last driver which is executed in a rayon thread, it can get a channel's tx by it's identify without storing it (to simplify the state change process).

I found the tx and rx of oneshot cannot be copies and they are not thread safe, and the send method of tx need ownership. So, I can't store the tx in main thread and let the last driver find it's tx by identify. But I can use mpsc to do that, I worte 2 demos and pasted it into the body of the question, but I have to create mpsc with capacity 1 and close it manually.

I wrote 2 demos, as bellow.I wonder if this is an appropriate and efficient use of mpsc?

Version implemented using oneshot, cannot work.

```
#[tokio::test]
pub async fn test_async() -> Result<()>{
    let mut executor = Executor::new();

    let res1 = executor.run(1).await?;
    let res2 = executor.run(2).await?;
    println!("res1 {}, res2 {}", res1, res2);
    Ok(())
}

struct Executor {
    pub pool: ThreadPool,
    pub txs: Arc<DashMap<i32, RwLock<oneshot::Sender<i32>>>>,
}

impl Executor {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Executor{
            pool: ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(10).build().unwrap(),
            txs: Arc::new(DashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self, index: i32) -> Result<i32> {
        let (tx, rx) = oneshot::channel();
        self.txs.insert(index, RwLock::new(tx));
        let txs_clone = self.txs.clone();
        self.pool.spawn(move || {
            let spawn_tx = txs_clone.get(&index).unwrap();
            let guard = block_on(spawn_tx.read());
            // cannot work, send need ownership, it will cause move of self
            guard.send(index);
        });

        let res = rx.await;
        return Ok(res.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Version implemented using mpsc, can work, not sure about performance

```
#[tokio::test]
pub async fn test_async() -> Result<()>{
    let mut executor = Executor::new();

    let res1 = executor.run(1).await?;
    let res2 = executor.run(2).await?;
    println!("res1 {}, res2 {}", res1, res2);
    // close channel after task finished
    executor.close(1);
    executor.close(2);
    Ok(())
}

struct Executor {
    pub pool: ThreadPool,
    pub txs: Arc<DashMap<i32, RwLock<mpsc::Sender<i32>>>>,
}

impl Executor {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Executor{
            pool: ThreadPoolBuilder::new().num_threads(10).build().unwrap(),
            txs: Arc::new(DashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    pub fn close(&mut self, index:i32) {
        self.txs.remove(&index);
    }

    pub async fn run(&mut self, index: i32) -> Result<i32> {
        let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);
        self.txs.insert(index, RwLock::new(tx));
        let txs_clone = self.txs.clone();
        self.pool.spawn(move || {
            let spawn_tx = txs_clone.get(&index).unwrap();
            let guard = block_on(spawn_tx.value().read());
            block_on(guard.deref().send(index));
        });
        // 0 mock invalid value
        let mut res:i32 = 0;
        while let Some(data) = rx.recv().await {
            println!("recv data {}", data);
            res = data;
            break;
        }
        return Ok(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should use future crate:https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.2/futures/struct.Complete.html.  I will try it.

Comment: That link is extremely old. Are you looking for a [oneshot](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/channel/oneshot/fn.channel.html)?

Comment: If you are using `tokio`, use [its `oneshot` channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) and not futures'.

Comment: @drewtato I had originally thought that the Future crate will provide similar function just like Java's CompletableFuture::complete.
If I use oneshot crate, I need to think about both tx and rx. But if I can create a empty Future and then complete it, I thought the code would be a little bit cleaner.
So, is the oneshot(or other channel) the only standard answer for sending a single value across asynchronous tasks?

Comment: @lulijun `CompletableFuture` relies on the future having two different owners. That's not a thing in Rust unless you wrap the entire thing in an `Arc`, which is unnecessary overhead. Splitting the responsibilities between a "completer" side (tx) and a "waiter" side (rx) fits the language much better. Hence oneshot channel. The capabilities are the same, it's not clear why you dislike it except that it's different from what you're used to.

Comment: @Masklinn What you wrote would make a good answer. The OP's question is not unreasonable, and is the kind of thing others coming from Java or [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) might ask. Using a oneshot channel for this purpose is obvious once someone more experienced points it out, but might not occur to one stuck inside the "future" paradigm.

Comment: Your scenario is pretty vague, which in turn means there are multiple different technical solutions which could possibly fit the vague description even though some would likely not work while you try to put them in practice. Could you sketch a design of what you are attempting to do? Is the thread creating the future blocking on it, or periodically checking whether it's complete and doing something else in the meantime?Will there be multiple futures concurrently awaiting termination? If so, will futures be completed in the order they are created, or not?

Comment: I agree, I don't think there's a perfect counterpart to `CompletableFuture` in rust. I think [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.25.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html) is closest if `oneshot` doesn't work.

Comment: @Masklinn I understood the design purpose of using oneshot for features like CompletableFuture.
I found that using oneshot in my scenarios didn't work, using mpsc did. But I'm not sure this is the most appropriate way.
I added the specific scenario description and code demo in the body of the problem.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  I added the specific scenario description and code demo in the body of the problem. At present, I think using mpsc can achieve the functions I need, but I am not sure if it is the most appropriate solution

Comment: @lulijun: It's unclear what the `DashMap` in both of your designs if supposed to be for. You insert, then immediately `get` in the spawned task. Why not just pass `tx` directly to the task?

Comment: Also not clear what the point of the `RwLock` is either, the entire point of a `oneshot::Sender` is that it is sent to once and consumed in the process, there's very little you can read out of it (pretty much just check if it's closed), and none of it is being done here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. DashMap is used to hold the tx of channel, the key of DashMap is the identify of Task.
The demo is just try to implement: a async task can get it's tx of channel from main thread. It doesn't do everything, because that would be too much code.
I can't pass the tx to the task, because the real scene is: "run" method will spawn a task, the first task will only produce a state, the state will trigger another spawn task, this is a hierarchical scheduling process. Only the last task(depends on task's config) will produce a output, as the input data of channel.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So I thought, if I pass the tx to the task, the hierarchical scheduling process will be more complex, spwan task need to pass it to next spawn task because only the last spwan task will send data to channel.

Comment: @Masklinn This is my incorrect use, I mistakenly thought that the sender in onshot and mpsc was thread-unsafe. RwLock can be removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: It's really hard to picture what you are attempting to achieve, because the examples provided are trivial to solve, with no justification for the added complexity (`DashMap`). As such, this answer will be progressive, though it will remain focused on solving the problem you demonstrated you had, and not necessarily the problem you're thinking of... as I have no crystal ball.*

We'll be using the following `Result` type in the examples:

```rust
type Result<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>>;
```

#### Serial execution

The simplest way to execute a task, is to do so right here, right now.

```rust
impl Executor {
    pub async fn run<F>(&self, task: F) -> Result<i32>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Future<Output = Result<i32>>,
    {
        task().await
    }
}
```

#### Async execution - built-in

When the execution of a task may involve heavy-weight calculations, it may be beneficial to execute it on a background thread.

Whichever runtime you are using probably supports this functionality, I'll demonstrate with [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html):

```rust
impl Executor {
    pub async fn run<F>(&self, task: F) -> Result<i32>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<i32>,
    {
        Ok(tokio::task::spawn_block(task).await??)
    }
}
```

#### Async execution - one-shot

If you wish to have more control on the number of CPU-bound threads, either to limit them, or to partition the CPUs of the machine for different needs, then the async runtime may not be configurable enough and you may prefer to use a thread-pool instead.

In this case, synchronization back with the runtime can be achieved via channels, the simplest of which being the `oneshot` channel.

```rust
impl Executor {
    pub async fn run<F>(&self, task: F) -> Result<i32>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<i32>,
    {
        let (tx, mut rx) = oneshot::channel();

        self.pool.spawn(move || {
            let result = task();

            //  Decide on how to handle the fact that nobody will read the result.
            let _ = tx.send(result);
        });

        Ok(rx.await??)
    }
}
```

---

Note that in all of the above solutions, `task` remains agnostic as to how it's executed. This is a property you should strive for, as it makes it easier to change the way execution is handled in the future by more neatly separating the two concepts.